# Definition of $\partial_r$ and Gauss Lemma (Petersen's Riemannian Geometry)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

From page 43 of [Petersen's Riemannian Geometry](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-29403-2):

> Let $U$ be an open subset of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and $r:U\to \mathbb R$ a distance function, then $\partial_r=\nabla r$ is the gradient.

So far, everything seems clear, but then I am confused on page $133$:

> The Gauss Lemma: On $(U, g)$ the function $r$ satisfies $\nabla r = \partial_r$,
> where $\partial_r = D\exp_p(\partial r)$.

Here $U$ is a suitable neighborhood of $p\in M$ and the equation $\nabla r = \partial_r$ is clearly not considered to be a definition. Furthermore, I am confused by the equation $\partial_r = D\exp_p(\partial_r)$. Is this an abuse of notation or is this equation telling us that $D\exp_p$ maps $\partial_r$ onto itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Petersen is mixing up two different, yet equivalent, definitions of $r$ here.

1. The first is as the distance function $r = d(\cdot,p)$.
   In that case, its gradient $\nabla r$ (in a punctured neighbourhood) is well defined as a local vector field on $M$.
2. The second is as a component in some specific coordinates, namely, the polar exponential coordinates
   $(r,\theta) \in (0,\varepsilon)\times \Bbb S \mapsto \exp_p(r\theta) \in M$, where $\Bbb S$ is the unit sphere of $T_pM$.
   On $(0,\varepsilon)\times \Bbb S$, there is a canonical vector field $\frac{d}{d r}$ which induces a local vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = (\exp_p)_*(\frac{d}{dr})$ on $M$.

It then follows from Gauss Lemma that these two notions give the same vector field, *i.e.* that $\nabla r = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}$.
It is usually denoted $\partial_r$ and called the radial vector field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). Do we really need to consider polar coordinates or could we alternatively define the vector field $X$ on the domain of $\exp_p$ by$$v\mapsto X(v):=\frac{v}{\|v\|}$$and then set$$\partial_r:=(\exp_p)_*X?$$

Comment: @Filippo This is an alternative (and equivalent) way of doing this, yes.

Comment: Great, thank you for the confirmation. I wanted a coordinate-free definition of the radial vector field. Now I have it.

Comment: @Filippo You're welcome. $\partial_r := \nabla r$ was already coordinate free definition though!

Comment: You are right. But "our" definition is more suitable for seeing the correlation between the velocity of geodesics and the radial vector field :)